# side list panel not open in google map

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have used the exact fiddle code,(https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/rf9bvks4/5/),all sections are working except the left side panel (i.e.) it is not shown. can you please suggest how can i solve this problem.i want the same fiddle which is used here.I don't need the search input box just want the left side list panel.

```js
   
    
    
    <script>
    var infoWindow;
    var map;
    function initMap() {
       // Create the map.
       map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
         zoom: 7,
         center: {
           lat: 32.434521,
           lng: -86.333977
         },
         // styles: mapStyle,
       });
    
       // Load the stores GeoJSON onto the map.
       map.data.addGeoJson(geoJsonData, {    
         idPropertyName: 'storeid'
       });
    
       // Define the custom marker icons, using the store's "category".
       map.data.setStyle((feature) => {
         return {
           icon: {
             url: 'https://staging.ymcamontgomery.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/map-marker-1.svg',
             scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(50, 50),
           },
         };
       });
    
    
    //   const apiKey = 'AIzaSyDmXhcX8z4d4GxPxIiklwNvtqxcjZoWsWU';
       infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
       // Show the information for a store when its marker is clicked.
       map.data.addListener('click', (event) => {
         openInfoWindowOnMarker(event.feature)
       });
    
       // SEARCH BAR
    
       // Build and add the search bar
       const card = document.createElement('div');
       const titleBar = document.createElement('div');
       const title = document.createElement('div');
       const container = document.createElement('div');
       const magnify = document.createElement('div');
       const input = document.createElement('input');    
       const options = {
         types: ['(regions)'],
         componentRestrictions: {
           country: 'us'
         },
       };
    
       card.setAttribute('id', 'pac-card');
       title.setAttribute('id', 'title');
       title.textContent = 'Find the nearest location';
       titleBar.appendChild(title);
       container.setAttribute('id', 'pac-container');
       magnify.setAttribute('id', 'magnify');
       input.setAttribute('id', 'pac-input');
       input.setAttribute('type', 'text');
       input.setAttribute('placeholder', 'ZIP CODE');
       input.setAttribute('value', 'Montgomery');
       container.appendChild(input);
       let parent = document.getElementById('map-hero');
       parent.appendChild(card);
       card.appendChild(titleBar);
       card.appendChild(container);
       let magnifyParent = document.getElementById('pac-container');
       magnifyParent.appendChild(magnify);
       // map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(card);
    
    
       // Make the search bar into a Places Autocomplete search bar and select
       // which detail fields should be returned about the place that
       // the user selects from the suggestions.
       const autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
    
       autocomplete.setFields(
         ['address_components', 'geometry', 'name']);
        
    
       // END SEARCH BAR
    
       // Press Enter to Search Zip Code
    
       var pac_input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
    
       (function pacSelectFirst(input) {
         // store the original event binding function
         var _addEventListener = (input.addEventListener) ? input.addEventListener : input.attachEvent;
    
         function addEventListenerWrapper(type, listener) {
           // Simulate a 'down arrow' keypress on hitting 'return' when no pac suggestion is selected,
           // and then trigger the original listener.
           if (type == "keydown") {
             var orig_listener = listener;
             listener = function(event) {
               var suggestion_selected = $(".pac-item-selected").length > 0;
               if (event.which == 13 && !suggestion_selected) {
                 var simulated_downarrow = $.Event("keydown", {
                   keyCode: 40,
                   which: 40
                 });
                 orig_listener.apply(input, [simulated_downarrow]);
               }
               orig_listener.apply(input, [event]);
             };
           }
           _addEventListener.apply(input, [type, listener]);
         }
         input.addEventListener = addEventListenerWrapper;
         input.attachEvent = addEventListenerWrapper;
    
         var autoComplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
         autoComplete.setTypes(['regions'])
         // autoComplete.unbindAll();
    
       })(pac_input);
       //End Press Enter to Search Zip Code
    
       //Click magnifying glass to search
    
       document.getElementById('magnify').onclick = function() {
         var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
    
         function no_op() {}
    
         google.maps.event.trigger(input, 'focus', {});
         google.maps.event.trigger(input, 'keydown', {
           keyCode: 40, // arrow down
           stopPropagation: no_op, // No-op function in order to prevent error
           preventDefault: no_op,
         });
         google.maps.event.trigger(input, 'keydown', {
           keyCode: 13
         }); // enter
         google.maps.event.trigger(this, 'focus', {});
       };
       //End Click magnifying glass to search
    
       // Set the origin point when the user selects an address
       const originMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
         map: map
       });
       originMarker.setVisible(false);
       let originLocation = map.getCenter();
    
       autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', async () => {
         originMarker.setVisible(false);
         originLocation = map.getCenter();
         const place = autocomplete.getPlace();
           alert(place.name);
    
         if (!place.geometry) {
           // User entered the name of a Place that was not suggested and
           // pressed the Enter key, or the Place Details request failed.
           window.alert('No address available for input: \'' + place.name + '\'');
           return;
         }
    
         // Recenter the map to the selected address
         originLocation = place.geometry.location;
         map.setCenter(originLocation);
         map.setZoom(9);
         console.log(place);
    
         originMarker.setPosition(originLocation);
         originMarker.setVisible(true);
    
         // Use the selected address as the origin to calculate distances
         // to each of the store locations
         const rankedStores = await calculateDistances(map.data, originLocation);
         showStoresList(map.data, rankedStores);
    
         return;
           
       });
    
     }
    
     function openInfoWindowOnMarker(feature) {
       console.log(feature);
       
       const name = feature.getProperty('name');     
       const address = feature.getProperty('address');
         console.log("test"+address);
       const phone = feature.getProperty('phone');
       const position = feature.getGeometry().get();
       const content = `<h5>${name}</h5><p>${address}</p><p>${phone}</p>`;
           
    
       infoWindow.setContent(content);
       infoWindow.setPosition(position);
       infoWindow.setOptions({
         pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(0, -30)
       });
       infoWindow.open(map);
     }
     // Calculate Distance
    
     async function calculateDistances(data, origin) {
       const stores = [];
       const destinations = [];
    
       // Build parallel arrays for the store IDs and destinations
       data.forEach((store) => {
         const storeNum = store.getProperty('storeid');
         const storeLoc = store.getGeometry().get();
    
         stores.push(storeNum);
         destinations.push(storeLoc);
       });
    
       // Retrieve the distances of each store from the origin
       // The returned list will be in the same order as the destinations list
       const service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
       const getDistanceMatrix =
         (service, parameters) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
           service.getDistanceMatrix(parameters, (response, status) => {
             if (status != google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
               reject(response);
             } else {
               const distances = [];
               const results = response.rows[0].elements;
                 alert(results);
               for (let j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {
                 const element = results[j];
                 if (element.status == "OK") {
                   const distanceText = element.distance.text;
                   const distanceVal = element.distance.value;
                   const distanceObject = {
                     storeid: stores[j],
                     storeLoc: destinations[j],
                     distanceText: distanceText,
                     distanceVal: distanceVal,
                   };
                   distances.push(distanceObject);
                 }
               }
    
               resolve(distances);
             }
           });
         });
    
       const distancesList = await getDistanceMatrix(service, {
         origins: [origin],
         destinations: destinations,
         travelMode: 'DRIVING',
         unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL,
       });
    
       distancesList.sort((first, second) => {
         return first.distanceVal - second.distanceVal;
       });
    
       return distancesList;
     }
    
     // End Calculate Distance
    
     //Show Closest Location List
     function showStoresList(data, stores) { 
          alert('test');
       if (stores.length == 0) {
         console.log('empty stores');
         return;
       }
    
       let panel = document.createElement('div');
      
       // If the panel already exists, use it. Else, create it and add to the page.
       if (document.getElementById('panel')) {
         panel = document.getElementById('panel');
         // If panel is already open, close it
         if (panel.classList.contains('open')) {
           panel.classList.remove('open');
         }
       } else {
         panel.setAttribute('id', 'panel');
         let parent = document.getElementById('map');
         parent.appendChild(panel);
    //       const body = document.body;
    //       body.insertBefore(panel, body.childNodes[0]);       
       }
        
         
    
    
       // Clear the previous details
       while (panel.lastChild) {
         panel.removeChild(panel.lastChild);
       }
    
       stores.forEach((store) => {
         console.log(store);
         // Add store details with text formatting
         const name = document.createElement('p');
         name.setAttribute('id', 'locationName');
         name.classList.add('place');
         const currentStore = data.getFeatureById(store.storeid);
         name.addEventListener('click', (function(currentStore) {
            
           return function() {
           openInfoWindowOnMarker(currentStore);
         }})(currentStore));
         name.textContent = currentStore.getProperty('name');
         panel.appendChild(name);
         const distanceText = document.createElement('p');
         distanceText.classList.add('distanceText');
         distanceText.textContent = store.distanceText;
         panel.appendChild(distanceText);
    
       });
    
       // Open the panel
       panel.classList.add('open');
    
       return;
        
     }
    
     //End Show Closest Location List
    
     var geoJsonData = {
       "type": "FeatureCollection",
       "features": [{
           "geometry": {
             "type": "Point",
             "coordinates": [-86.192867,
               32.346155
             ]
           },
           "type": "Feature",
           "properties": {
             "name": "Place 1",
             "address": "The Address",
             "phone": "The Number",
             "storeid": "01"
           }
         },
         {
           "geometry": {
             "type": "Point",
             "coordinates": [-86.305915,
               32.366245
             ]
           },
           "type": "Feature",
           "properties": {
             "name": "Place 2",
             "address": "The Address",
             "phone": "The Number",
             "storeid": "02"
           }
         },
         {
           "geometry": {
             "type": "Point",
             "coordinates": [-85.7077266,
               32.430237
             ]
           },
           "type": "Feature",
           "properties": {
             "name": "Tuskegee",
             "address": "Tuskegee",
             "phone": "The Number",
             "storeid": "03"
           }
         },
         {
           "geometry": {
             "type": "Point",
             "coordinates": [151.2092955,
               -33.8688197 
             ]
           },
           "type": "Feature",
           "properties": {
             "name": "Sydney",
             "address": "Sydney NSW",
             "phone": "The Number",
             "storeid": "04"
           }
         },
         {
           "geometry": {
             "type": "Point",
             "coordinates": [-74.0059728 ,
               40.7127753
             ]
           },
           "type": "Feature",
           "properties": {
             "name": "New York",
             "address": "New York, NY",
             "phone": "The Number",
             "storeid": "05"
           }
         },
         {
           "geometry": {
             "type": "Point",
             "coordinates": [-71.05888 ,
               42.3600825
             ]
           },
           "type": "Feature",
           "properties": {
             "name": "Boston",
             "address": "Boston, MA",
             "phone": "The Number",
             "storeid": "06"
           }
         },
         {
           "geometry": {
             "type": "Point",
             "coordinates": [-80.1917902,
               25.7616798
             ]
           },
           "type": "Feature",
           "properties": {
             "name": "Miami",
             "address": "Miami, FL",
             "phone": "The Number",
             "storeid": "07"
           }
         },
       ]
     }
```

```css
 /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
     * element that contains the map. */
    /* #map {
      height: 100%;
    } */
    /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
    html,
    body {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    #map {
      height: 400px;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    .map-hero {
      /* background-image: url('my url'); */
      background-size: cover;
      background-position: center;
      min-height: 355px;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: center;
    }
    
    .center-info-bar {
      margin-bottom: 0;
    }
    
    .sidebar {
      display: none;
    }
    
    .content {
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    .gm-style-iw-c {
      padding: 25px;
      width: 300px;
    }
    
    .gm-style-iw-d {
      height: auto;
    }
    
    .map-loc-name {
      font-size: 15px;
      font-weight: bold;
      width: 100%;
      margin-bottom: 15px;
    }
    
    #pac-card {
      background-color: #fff;
      border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
      box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
      box-sizing: border-box;
      font-family: Roboto;
      margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
      -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
      outline: none;
      // custom
      max-width: 300px;
      background: transparent;
      box-shadow: none;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    
    #pac-container {
      padding-top: 12px;
      padding-bottom: 12px;
      margin-right: 12px;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
    }
    
    #pac-input {
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
      // custom
      width: 100%;
      padding: 15px;
      border: 3px solid #C11589;
      border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;
      background: transparent;
      color: #000;
      font-size: 18px;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-family: 'Cachet-Bold', Verdana, sans-serif;
    }
    
    #pac-input::placeholder {
      color: #fff;
      font-family: 'Cachet-Bold', Verdana, sans-serif;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 18px;
    }
    
    input:focus {
      box-shadow: none;
    }
    
    #magnify {
      width: 50px;
      height: 58px;
      border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0;
      background-color: #C11589;
      /*  background-image: url('my url'); */
      background-size: 80%;
      background-position: center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
    
    #magnify:hover {
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    #title {
      color: #fff;
      background-color: #acbcc9;
      font-size: 18px;
      font-weight: 400;
      padding: 6px 12px;
      // custom
      display: none;
    }
    
    .hidden {
      display: none;
    }
    
    /* Styling for an info pane that slides out from the left. 
               * Hidden by default. */
    #panel {
      height: 100%;
      width: null;
      background-color: red!important;
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 1;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      transition: all .2s ease-out;
    }
    
    .open {
      width: 250px;
        background: red;
    }
    
    .place {
      font-family: 'open sans', arial, sans-serif;
      font-size: 1.2em;
      font-weight: 500;
      margin-block-end: 0px;
      padding-left: 18px;
      padding-right: 18px;
    }
    
    .distanceText {
      color: silver;
      font-family: 'open sans', arial, sans-serif;
      font-size: 1em;
      font-weight: 400;
      margin-block-start: 0.25em;
      padding-left: 18px;
      padding-right: 18px;
    }
```

```html
    <html>
    <head><title>final code store locator</title>
    </script>
     <!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
    <!-- <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDmXhcX8z4d4GxPxIiklwNvtqxcjZoWsWU=initMap&libraries=places" async defer></script> -->
    <script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDmXhcX8z4d4GxPxIiklwNvtqxcjZoWsWU&libraries=places&callback=initMap">    
    </script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
    <div id="map-hero" class="map-hero">
            <h1 class="white center">GET STARTED BY ENTERING YOUR ZIP CODE</h1>
            <h4 class="white center">You can also zoom and drag to find a location nearest you</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="center-info-bar">
            <div id="map"></div>
    
        </div>
    
    
    
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: That is way too much code. Please shorten the code snippet to focus only on areas you think is/are causing the problem.

Comment: i am new in stack over flow. please advice and give me solution